# REST service multipart brings "Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, multipartform-data

I've implemented a REST service on Glassfish server (GF4) and also a small client program to test it. But the server responds with a "Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type" error. Please have a look at my code and give me some hints.

Server code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;

@Path("generic")
public class GenericResource {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public GenericResource() {
        System.out.println("Mediatype: "+MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    }

    @Path("post")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void postXml(javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart multiPart) {
        try {
            System.out.println(multiPart.getCount());
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GenericResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my client code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class URLTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URLTester http = new URLTester();
        http.sendPost();
    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {
        String filename = "C:\\development\\java\\URLTester\\test.obx";
        String xml = readXML(filename);
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/RESTgarbio2oex/webresources/generic/post";

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        // MultiPart POST
        FileBody fb = new FileBody(new File(filename));

        post.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", fb);
        multipartEntity.addTextBody("data", "Here is the data.");
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine.toString());
        }
    }

    private String readXML(String xmlsource) {
        String xml = "";
        try {
            File in = new File(xmlsource);
            xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(in);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(URLTester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return xml;
    }    
}
```

As you can see, I'm setting the content type to `"multipart/form-data"` and use a MultipartEntityBuilder to create the data to send. I also use the Apache HTTPClientBuilder class to post the data to the server.

On server side, the `postXml` method isn't called at all, even when my debug console says the constructer has been called and puts `Mediatype: multipart/form-data` as result.

If you need further infos, please let me know. I've googled so many sites, but haven't come across a solution for my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Long shot, have you tried with Content-Type instead? Not sure if casing works. 2. What body readers are registered?

Comment: try post.setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Sorry, both hints didn't work. No typo from me, even that would be the most errors done by myself :) Where can I see which body readers are registered? In glassfish on server side?

Comment: I tried your code and it works...maybe its a problem with the version of the apache libs you are using. I used version 4.3-beta2 of httpcore, httpclient and httpmime from org.apache.httpcomponents. If this doesn't solve your problem you should check the HTTP header which is really sent to the server with wireshark or something similar.

Comment: I'm using version 4.3.1 (GA) from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi. I have checked the HTTP protocols with wireshark and even there it seems correct: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and the data which is sent looks also correct. I'll try to send it via HTML form as next, just to look if there is a difference.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am also getting same issue.